# how to convert a phoenix API to use the --no-html flag

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm presently working on a phx / phoenix project written using Elixir.  I created the project with the below command, and with the intention of the project being an API.

```
mix phx.new kegcopr_api --app kegcopr_api --module KegCopRAPI --no-brunch
```

However, I forgot to specify the `--no-html` flag when creating the project.  Is it possible to convert this project to use the `--no-html` flag?  Or do I need to create a whole new project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any automated way to convert it. You could manually remove the html related files and folders:

- assets (might not be there with --no-brunch)
- lib/kegcopr_api/web/templates
- lib/kegcopr_api/web/page_controller.ex
- lib/kegcopr_api/web/views/page_view.ex
- lib/kegcopr_api/web/view/layout_view.ex

and the related test files.

You should also remove the phoenix_html dependency.

However, presuming you've only edited a hand full of files, then create a new project and copy over the edited files to the new project.

Comment: Also, make sure to remove / comment out all lines in project source that state `use Phoenix.HTML`

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already started working on your application, the easiest thing to do would be to just delete the project and start over.

If you have already started it, you can just delete the HTML files and remove the `phoenix_html` dependency from your application.